# Working on multidimensional arrays

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, scikit-image

I'm trying to scale the colors of images to predefined ranges. Based on least-squared error from palette's range of colors, a color is assigned to output pixel.

I have written the code in python loops is there a better vectorized way to do this?

```
import numpy as np
import skimage.io as io

palette = [
            [180, 0 , 0],
            [255, 150, 0],
            [255, 200, 0],
            [0, 128, 0]
        ]

IMG = io.imread('lena.jpg')[:,:,:3]
DIM = IMG.shape
IOUT = np.empty(DIM)

for x in range(DIM[0]):
    for y in range(DIM[1]):
        P = ((np.array(palette)-IMG[x,y,:])**2).sum(axis=1).argmin()
        IOUT[x,y,:] = palette[P]
```

Can the loops be avoided and solved using numpy operations itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't loop over all pixels, but over all colors:

```py
import pylab as pl

palette = pl.array([[180, 0, 0], [255, 150, 0], [255, 200, 0], [0, 128, 0]])

img = pl.imread('lena.jpg')[:, :, :3].astype('float')
R, G, B = img[:, :, 0].copy(), img[:, :, 1].copy(), img[:, :, 2].copy()
dist = pl.inf * R

for i in range(len(palette)):
    new_dist = pl.square(img[:, :, 0] - palette[i, 0]) \
             + pl.square(img[:, :, 1] - palette[i, 1]) \
             + pl.square(img[:, :, 2] - palette[i, 2])
    R[new_dist < dist] = palette[i, 0]
    G[new_dist < dist] = palette[i, 1]
    B[new_dist < dist] = palette[i, 2]
    dist = pl.minimum(dist, new_dist)

pl.clf()
pl.subplot(1, 2, 1)
pl.imshow(img.astype('uint8'))
pl.subplot(1, 2, 2)
pl.imshow(pl.dstack((R, G, B)))
```

---

**Edit:** The loop-less alternative. ;)

```
import pylab as pl

palette = pl.array([[180, 0 , 0], [255, 150, 0], [255, 200, 0], [0, 128, 0]])

img = pl.imread('lena.jpg')[:, :, :3]
pl.clf()
pl.subplot(1, 2, 1)
pl.imshow(img)

IMG = img.reshape((512, 512, 3, 1))
PAL = palette.transpose().reshape((1, 1, 3, -1))
idx = pl.argmin(pl.sum((IMG - PAL)**2, axis=2), axis=2)
img = palette[idx, :]
pl.subplot(1, 2, 2)
pl.imshow(img)
```

Comment: Something is amiss. I get single value for complete array.

Comment: Where exactly? It runs smoothly in my Python 2.7.8 interpreter with NumPy 1.8.1, SciPy 0.14.0, Matplotlib 1.3.1.

Comment: for 1, image values are read as decimals. rather than 0-255 scale. I think, that's the problem.

Comment: Oh, ok. You didn't provide the Lena test image. Therefore I quickly grabbed one from the internet which is a bmp and is in [0..255] after ```imread```. You might scale your image accordingly to match your color palette.

Comment: Tried scaling as well. And, the images produced from both methods and the inefficient-for-loops methods are different.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59014/discussion-between-falko-and-ankurgupta).